# Load namespaced library from component in J!4

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4, libraries, autoload, namespace

I'm using the latest build of J!4. I have a component that has library files under `joomla_root\libraries\mycomponent` but the namespaced files in this directory aren't loaded by Joomla! 4 autoloader.

So what is the way to do it in Joomla4?

Comment: Can you share the code you're currently using to try and load them?

Comment: The package of the component has the component itself and the libraries(com_mycomponent, the libraries) each has his one xml, i have added in the xml <namespace>Mycomponent\Subname\Libraries</namespace> and i trying to load the libraries by calling \JLoader::registerNamespace('Mycomponent\\Subname\\Libraries\\', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/mycomponent');

Comment: Please update your original question with the formatted code. Maybe this has something to do with it: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/27459